# Insertion Sort from Right to left with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, insertion-sort

I am trying to write an insertion sort function that works from right to left.
Not in descending order. I just am not understanding why this code would not properly sort numbers.

```
function reverseInsertionSort(arr) { 
for(var i = arr.length -1; i >0; i--) 
var val = arr[i];
    var j;
    for(j = i; j > 0 && arr[j-1] < val; j--) {
        arr[j-1] = arr[j]; }
     va=arr[j]; }
function insertionSort(arr) { 
    for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) { 
        var val = arr[i];
        var j;
        for(j = i; j > 0 && arr[j-1] > val; j--) {
            arr[j] = arr[j-1]; }
        arr[j] = val; }
    }
            arr[j] = val;
        }
    }
var length = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1;
var arr = new Array();
for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*10000)+1);
}
var arr2= arr.slice();

reverseInsertionSort(arr2);
console.log(arr2)
```

It is not sorted, and the output ends in undefined. 
arr is being used to test the insertionsort fun
Happy to accept constructive criticism.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insertion Sort Algorithm on JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33530928/insertion-sort-algorithm-on-javascript)

Comment: i have an insertion sort. it works normally and goes from left to right. I am trying to do the same thing but from the other end of the array

Comment: Since you said criticism is welcome... this kind of code looks `minified` to me. Scary, will never review them. maybe make those single char variable more descriptive. 1 or 2 lines of comment to state certain behaviour or reason for having the code would be nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work.

```
function reverseInsertionSort(arr) { 

    for(var i = arr.length-2; i>=0; i--) {

        var value = arr[i];
        var j;

        for(j = i; ((j < arr.length) && (arr[j+1] > value)); j++){ 
            arr[j] = arr[j+1]; 
        } 
        arr[j] = value;
    }
    return arr;
}

//test
var inputArray = [3,2,4,5,1,10,23];
var resultArray = reverseInsertionSort(inputArray);
console.log(resultArray); //[23, 10, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: I see. We want to start 2 before the end so that we can compare the last with the second to last on the first run through. Thank you very much.

Comment: This sorts in descending. I need to sort in ascending. Flipped the sign on arr[j+1]>val and it worked like a charm :D

Comment: 1) I started from 2 last element just to demostrate logic behind insertion sort more clearly. It should work as the same even if we use `arr.length-1`. 2) I am glad that I left it for you to figure it out. 

Answer (score 1):

You should start the outer loop from the last element ie. len-1. The undefined member of the array is created due to your outer loop starting from arr.length .
Try this :

```
function insSort(arr){
  for(var i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    key=arr[i];
    j=i+1;
    while(j<arr.length&&arr[j]<=key){
      arr[j-1]=arr[j];
      j++;
    }
    arr[j-1]=key;
  }
}
var length = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1;
var arr = new Array();
for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*10000)+1);
}
console.log(arr);
insSort(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: It is still out of order with those changes
`code
 function reverseInsertionSort(arr) { 
 for(var i = arr.length -1; i >0; i--) 
 var val = arr[i];
  var j;
  for(j = i+1; j > 0 && arr[j-1] < val; j--) {
   arr[j-1] = arr[j]; }
   va=arr[j]; }
`

Comment: Even plugging your code in directly results in an incorrectly sorted array.

Comment: I've updated the code. Try that . Codepen : https://codepen.io/Sarthak_SG/pen/OdOEMG